# Vaadin StringLengthValidator allowNull parameter does not work

Tags: java, validation, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a `TextField` and i am tyring to add a StringLengthValidator in order to validate it as below.

```
    txtName.setRequired(false);
    txtName.addValidator(new StringLengthValidator(
            "The title field must be at least 3 characters in length", 3, 75, true));
```

I want this text field to accept null/empty values as well as `

> at least 3 characters in length", 3, 75

rule so i set allowNull parameter as true. But it does not work. I still have to enter text values with at least 3 characters and at most 75 characters. How do fix this problem ? Any help would be aprreciated.

`

Comment: The documentation mentions that the allowNull is deprecated. Have you tried with field required=false? https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.7/com/vaadin/data/validator/StringLengthValidator.html#StringLengthValidator(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Integer,%20java.lang.Integer,%20boolean)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue and this seems like a bug to me. Even though I set additionally `setNullRepresentation("")` on the text field the `StringLengthValidator` is called with the empty string `""` to be validated, which fails of course because `""` has length zero.

To solve your issue you could derive the validator and override `isValidValue` to accept empty strings. Or write your own validator.